# Url Rewriting for Html pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess for url redirect. I have tried lot of things but it is giving me "NOT FOUND" ERROR

My current Url is

```
http://localhost:8089/travell/search.html?/india/goa
```

I need the url to be

```
http://localhost:8089/vacation/india/goa
```

My htaccess file is having

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?search.html http://localhost:8089/vacation?%{Query_string} [P]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing reverse in your rule. Use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^vacation/(.+)$ travell/search.html?$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Then test it by entering `http://localhost:8089/vacation/india/goa` in browser.

Comment: sorry it didnt work.I think it is trying to search vacation folder at the root

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser and what is location of this .htaccess? If there are more rule in .htaccess then place it in question.

Comment: only one rule i mentioned above.It is placed in travell folder.I think i should keep the .htaccess file in root

Comment: Yes you need to keep this in root as I mentioned in my answer.